# Youtube live stream publish from android / iOS App

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to integrate youtube live streaming publishing functionality in android / iOS app. I tried using `liveStreams insert` api and `liveBroadcast bind & insert api` but it shows waiting for the uploader. Iam using the rtmp link to upload the video stream from my app.

Can anybody help me with the integration or anything is missing?

Comment: Hi Mohammed, did you find any solution to this problem??

Comment: Yes I used LFLiveKIT for iOS and yasea for Android. These library helps you to send video stream from your app to YouTube then you need to bind the video using bind api and then you need to use transition api to change status to live. Transition api is to be called 10 seconds after binding api otherwise it will give error on changing status.

Comment: Thanks, Mohammed for the info. I'm a little confused now. I've called 3 youtube APIs - first live stream, second broadcast, and third bind. After calling bind API, I got the RTMP stream URL. Now I'm live streaming using LFLiveKIT on this RTMP stream URL but on youtube, it is saying coming soon/ waiting for Prashant. Could you please tell me if I'm missing anything here?

Comment: RTMP url consists of RTMP url address and Stream Key. Did you add the stream key to the url?

Comment: Yes, this is how my final stream URL looks like - rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/qgwf-gezt-sd3w-grws-bmkk

Comment: Did you grant every permission to the app and check if there is any button on ui which start/stop sending stream?

Comment: Yes, I have given all the permissions like a camera and a microphone. Also, yes I have a button on the navigation bar to start and stop the streaming.

Comment: So did you try clicking the button and check whether it is working?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Faiyyaz/4c4dfea2b588676a3c975c819946d6f3 My code snippet

Comment: Also just a note that simulator won't work for stream

Comment: Yes, I clicked the start and stop button but on youtube, it is showing like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XphUo-DX4HQ&feature=youtu.be and yes I'm trying on an actual device.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code snippet. Looks like my problem is I'm not calling change state API. I will try that.

Comment: Change state api is need if you are doing it programatically is your go live button was not  highlighted as red color?

Comment: It's highlighted as a red color but I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: Okay then use the API of change state with a 10 seconds delay after tapping start

Comment: I'm trying to consume the transition API to change the status. Am I right here?

Comment: and from where you get the broadcast ID and I guess you are sending status as "live".

Comment: yes i m sending it live and broadcast ID you get from bind or from create broadcast response

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, one more thing. I can see the Go Live button on youtube in blue color only. I don't want the user to manually click that button. How can we do this programmatically?

Comment: Use the transititon api call with a 10 seconds delay after user press start button in your iOS app. See my code for reference you will understand.

Comment: Yes, I used the same. It's working now. Thank you so much for your guidance

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue using LFLivekit for iOS and yasea RTMP library for Android.

The code snippet for swift is available on this link

https://gist.github.com/Faiyyaz/4c4dfea2b588676a3c975c819946d6f3